# How to use Solr post query get data count by year or month?

Tags: solr

My solr version is 6.1.0

I want to use solr post query to get data count by year or month,

this is my solr schema :

Field : value

"id":"..."

"title":"..."

"content":"..."

"siteurl":"..."

"author":"..."

"editor":"..."

"created":"2012-11-05T05:35:09Z"

"last_modified":"2012-11-05T05:35:09Z"

"links":"..."

"ListGUID":"..."

"ItemGUID":"..."

"iss":"..."

"soltyp":"..."

"source_type":"..."

"content_type":"..."

created and last_modified field typy is date,

And I want get every year or every month data count by keyword search,

it does work? or I need add year or month field?

Answer (score 0):

your question needs a bit more explaining, but, if you want to run some keyword search and facet results on a date field, you do it like this. I am querying for 'abc' in title (as an example), and faceting on last_modified (this should be a tdate field):

```
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/query -d 'q=title:abc&rows=0&json.facet={
 per_month: { range : {
  field : last_modified,
  start:'2012-01-01T00:00:00Z',
  end:'2016-12-31T23:59:59Z',
  gap:'+1MONTH',
 }}
}}'
```

Note that you can add more facets inside that one, to further slice your data.